# What are the config files that need to be change for 100% control over a postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, debian

I'm currently trying to set up a small PostgreSQL database server with Debian Linux and I would like to do everything from another machine.

The network we're using is sterile, all the computers access our corporate intranet and internet via proxy and all the computers have anti malware/virus/blablabla software installed.

What are the configurations that need to be changed so I can have full access to the PostgreSQL server?

I already have a SSH server working and running correctly and I already managed to allow database connections from other computers by editing the file postgresql.conf

But now pgAdminIII gives a FATAL error: no entry on pg_hba.conf

I tried editing the file manually but that was a really bad idea, when I tried to restart the server, it would fail when trying to get the parameters from pg_hba.conf.

After fixing the conf file I just started losing hope.

What am I doing wrong? Is setting up a SQL server supposed to be **THIS** hard? I mean, FTP servers weren't this hard! Heck, making a router out of a linux box wasn't so hard!

Comment: When editing configuration files RCS is still your friend, despite its age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally do edit this file manually and if you want to let everyone access you add something like

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

to it. By convention it does not qualify for being **this** hard.

Comment: I'm sorry about 'this hard'. I'm just really frustrated! I've been trying to get this server working for almost a week now, and I feel I'm still struggling with simple concepts. The line you mention to let everyone access - that should be added to pg_hba.conf rite?

Comment: I am really grateful. Thanks Michael.

Comment: You're welcome and no problem, it's just that I couldn't resist the comment about 'this hard' :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall. The firewall and proxy can do block remote access to postgreSQL. 
Allow postgres port in your firewall.

Check this link too: [pg_hba documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

When I had that kind of mistake, it was actually the case of firewall.

Hope this help.

Comment: This — "no entry on pg_hba.conf" — is a hint that it's not a connectivity issue, the message originates from the backend. But when it comes to network, I'd add the `listen` directive and friends in `postgresql.conf` to your list.

Answer (score 0):

Debian is just like Ubuntu, check [the fine manual about how to install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/postgresql.html), it's all there. You will be up and running within minutes.